# Get the Authenticated User's email?

Tags: support, api-v2, users, email

We're building the website for our local Developer Community. We're trying to enable "Login with Stack Exchange" (we already got LinkedIn and GitHub), but I can't seem to find the User's **email** when querying:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me/

But it doesn't seem to have the Email address of the user:

[image]

We are passing both `key` and `access_token` of the authorized user (that we got from `SE.authenticate()`).

Is there any other end-point that we need to query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API does not provide any method to determine a user's email address and it is unlikely to do so in the future.
This would be a risk to both the user's privacy and his/her trust in Stack Exchange. And, a pressing need for this information has yet to be demonstrated, regarding the API.

Note that [Stack Exchange refuses to even provide the user's email *hash* via the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/394/can-there-be-a-way-to-find-a-user-given-his-email-hash), even though this information [was once available via the data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/148310).
(Providing email would be much more egregious than providing the hash.)

Even a typical auth warning like: `"This application asks for your email and will do unspeakable things with it."` is not sufficient protection.
A naive/underage/frazzled/rushed user often won't realize the risk/ramifications when they see such a notice, before clicking "approve". But they *will* remember that "that sucky Overflow site gave away my email!" ;-)

---

## If your app really needs the user's email, *ask the user for it directly*.

They then can decide if they want to divulge that information.

Comment: Alright. I didn't see any documentation stating it, so I was hopeful. Maybe something like that should be added somewhere, just stating exactly the above.

Comment: What is the point o oauth2 if i can not get user email? I do not see any good thing from oauth2 feature on stackapps.com.

Comment: @pregmatch, The point is you CAN see several things that are normally private to the user; refer to the API docs for a list. (Technically, only your app should see these things.  Personally looking for this info is usually a major breach of trust.) ... ... Since **your app is supposed to help the *user*, why would you need to tell him his own email?**  If you need it for some other reason, ask the user directly.

Comment: "This would be a risk to [...] the user's privacy"? So would allowing an app to read a user's inbox. Or, say, perform writes on behalf of the user. Yet those scopes are available. An 'email' scope is pretty standard. This is part of what OAuth is for. No upvote from me based on the opinions expressed in answer, despite the information about the unavailability of email notbeing useful (no downvote, either)

Comment: The difference between write-access to one app and access to an email is like comparing a firecracker to a box of TNT.  You don't agree? Take it up on Meta.SE. It has been discussed extensively.

Comment: Even Facebook, GitHub and LinkedIn all provide user email when asked with the adequate scope... Do you believe they break their user's trust by doing so, and you don't? This actually sounds a bit pedantic.