# please expose stackauth via a url that is consistent with the api

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Most libraries and apps need to version themselves by adding the version number to the url and subsequently most of the http request code includes this information in the url building process.

the deviation of the stackauths url necessitates implementation of an additional http stack.

When you consider the amount of code and logic involved in implementing a stable and fault tolerant request strategy, modifying/adding to the stackauths url makes more sense than adding to the workload of the developers that are driving exposure to the StackOverflow brand.

What I would like to see in order to make stackauth a transparent enhancement to existing code:

- [http://stackauth.com/X.X/help/method?method=users/{id}/associated](http://stackauth.com/X.X/help/method?method=users/%7Bid%7D/associated)
- http://stackauth.com/X.X/help/method?method=sites

and

- [http://stackauth.com/X.X/{id}/associated](http://stackauth.com/X.X/%7Bid%7D/associated)
- http://stackauth.com/X.X/sites