# Array of all Stack Exchange sites with Name, URL and Description

Tags: support, scripts, sites

I'm building a WordPress widget and need this array do display a dropdown where the user will select the target site.

And with the selection value, the information will be built and displayed accordingly.

I'm not sure if there's an automated way of doing this, but having it hardcoded is much faster than doing any query.

I understand this is not a duplicate of [Should there be a discovery API?](https://stackapps.com/q/30/10590), as the intention is a raw list. Also thought of the answers being language specific in Community Wiki mode so they can be maintained/updated as new sites are created.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP

```
/**
 * 101 sites sorted alphabetically
 * Updated 2013.04.14
 */
$se_sites = array (
  'academia' => array(
    'Academia',
    'http://academia.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for academics and those enrolled in higher education',
  ),
  'android' => array(
    'Android Enthusiasts',
    'http://android.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system',
  ),
  'anime' => array(
    'Anime & Manga',
    'http://anime.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for anime and manga fans',
  ),
  'answers.onstartups' => array(
    'Answers OnStartups',
    'http://answers.onstartups.com',
    'Q&A for entrepreneurs looking to start or run a new business',
  ),
  'apple' => array(
    'Ask Different',
    'http://apple.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for power users of Apple hardware and software',
  ),
  'askubuntu' => array(
    'Ask Ubuntu',
    'http://askubuntu.com',
    'Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers',
  ),
  'avp' => array(
    'Audio-Video Production',
    'http://avp.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts spanning the fields of audio, video, and media creation',
  ),
  'bicycles' => array(
    'Bicycles',
    'http://bicycles.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for people who build and repair bicycles, people who train cycling, or commute on bicycles',
  ),
  'biology' => array(
    'Biology',
    'http://biology.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for biology researchers, academics, and students',
  ),
  'bitcoin' => array(
    'Bitcoin',
    'http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for Bitcoin crypto-currency enthusiasts',
  ),
  'boardgames' => array(
    'Board & Card Games',
    'http://boardgames.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for people who like playing board games, designing board games or modifying the rules of existing board games',
  ),
  'bricks' => array(
    'LEGO® Answers',
    'http://bricks.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for LEGO® and building block enthusiasts',
  ),
  'chemistry' => array(
    'Chemistry',
    'http://chemistry.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for scientists, academics, teachers and students',
  ),
  'chess' => array(
    'Chess',
    'http://chess.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for serious players and enthusiasts of chess',
  ),
  'chinese' => array(
    'Chinese Language & Usage',
    'http://chinese.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Chinese language',
  ),
  'christianity' => array(
    'Christianity',
    'http://christianity.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more',
  ),
  'codegolf' => array(
    'Programming Puzzles & Code Golf',
    'http://codegolf.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers',
  ),
  'codereview' => array(
    'Code Review',
    'http://codereview.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for peer programmer code reviews',
  ),
  'cogsci' => array(
    'Cognitive Sciences',
    'http://cogsci.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for practitioners, researchers, and students in cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry',
  ),
  'cooking' => array(
    'Seasoned Advice',
    'http://cooking.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for professional and amateur chefs',
  ),
  'crypto' => array(
    'Cryptography',
    'http://crypto.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for software developers, mathematicians and others interested in cryptography',
  ),
  'cs' => array(
    'Computer Science',
    'http://cs.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science',
  ),
  'cstheory' => array(
    'Theoretical Computer Science',
    'http://cstheory.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for theoretical computer scientists and researchers in related fields',
  ),
  'dba' => array(
    'Database Administrators',
    'http://dba.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in  the community',
  ),
  'diy' => array(
    'Home Improvement',
    'http://diy.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for contractors and serious DIYers',
  ),
  'drupal' => array(
    'Drupal Answers',
    'http://drupal.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for Drupal developers and administrators',
  ),
  'dsp' => array(
    'Signal Processing',
    'http://dsp.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for practitioners of the art and science of signal, image and video processing',
  ),
  'electronics' => array(
    'Electrical Engineering',
    'http://electronics.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts',
  ),
  'ell' => array(
    'English Language Learners',
    'http://ell.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for speakers of other languages learning English',
  ),
  'english' => array(
    'English Language & Usage',
    'http://english.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts',
  ),
  'expressionengine' => array(
    'ExpressionEngine® Answers',
    'http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for administrators, end users, developers and designers for ExpressionEngine® CMS',
  ),
  'fitness' => array(
    'Physical Fitness',
    'http://fitness.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for physical fitness professionals, athletes, trainers, and those providing health-related needs',
  ),
  'french' => array(
    'French Language & Usage',
    'http://french.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the French language',
  ),
  'gamedev' => array(
    'Game Development',
    'http://gamedev.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for professional and independent game developers',
  ),
  'gaming' => array(
    'Arqade',
    'http://gaming.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for passionate videogamers on all platforms',
  ),
  'gardening' => array(
    'Gardening & Landscaping',
    'http://gardening.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for gardeners and landscapers',
  ),
  'genealogy' => array(
    'Genealogy & Family History',
    'http://genealogy.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history',
  ),
  'german' => array(
    'German Language & Usage',
    'http://german.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for speakers of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation',
  ),
  'gis' => array(
    'Geographic Information Systems',
    'http://gis.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for cartographers, geographers and GIS professionals',
  ),
  'graphicdesign' => array(
    'Graphic Design',
    'http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for professional graphic designers and non-designers trying to do their own graphic design',
  ),
  'hermeneutics' => array(
    'Biblical Hermeneutics',
    'http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for professors, theologians, and those interested in exegetical analysis of biblical texts',
  ),
  'history' => array(
    'History',
    'http://history.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for historians and history buffs',
  ),
  'homebrew' => array(
    'Homebrewing',
    'http://homebrew.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for dedicated home brewers and serious enthusiasts',
  ),
  'islam' => array(
    'Islam',
    'http://islam.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for muslims, experts in Islam, and those interested in learning more about Islam',
  ),
  'japanese' => array(
    'Japanese Language & Usage',
    'http://japanese.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language',
  ),
  'judaism' => array(
    'Mi Yodeya',
    'http://judaism.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more',
  ),
  'libraries' => array(
    'Libraries & Information Science',
    'http://libraries.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for librarians and library professionals',
  ),
  'linguistics' => array(
    'Linguistics',
    'http://linguistics.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for professional linguists and others with an interest in linguistic research and theory',
  ),
  'magento' => array(
    'Magento',
    'http://magento.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for users of the Magento e-Commerce platform',
  ),
  'martialarts' => array(
    'Martial Arts',
    'http://martialarts.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for students and teachers of all martial arts',
  ),
  'math' => array(
    'Mathematics',
    'http://math.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields',
  ),
  'mathematica' => array(
    'Mathematica',
    'http://mathematica.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for users of Mathematica',
  ),
  'mechanics' => array(
    'Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair',
    'http://mechanics.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for mechanics and DIY enthusiast owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles',
  ),
  'meta.stackoverflow' => array(
    'Meta Stack Overflow',
    'http://meta.stackoverflow.com',
    'Q&A for the Stack Exchange engine powering these sites',
  ),
  'money' => array(
    'Personal Finance & Money',
    'http://money.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for people who want to be financially literate',
  ),
  'movies' => array(
    'Movies & TV',
    'http://movies.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for movie and tv enthusiasts',
  ),
  'music' => array(
    'Musical Practice & Performance',
    'http://music.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for musicians, students, and enthusiasts',
  ),
  'outdoors' => array(
    'The Great Outdoors',
    'http://outdoors.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for people who love outdoor activities, excursions, and outdoorsmanship',
  ),
  'parenting' => array(
    'Parenting',
    'http://parenting.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for parents, grandparents, nannies and others with a parenting role',
  ),
  'patents' => array(
    'Ask Patents',
    'http://patents.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for people interested in improving and participating in the patent system',
  ),
  'philosophy' => array(
    'Philosophy',
    'http://philosophy.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for those interested in logical reasoning',
  ),
  'photo' => array(
    'Photography',
    'http://photo.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for professional, enthusiast and amateur photographers',
  ),
  'physics' => array(
    'Physics',
    'http://physics.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for active researchers, academics and students of physics',
  ),
  'pm' => array(
    'Project Management',
    'http://pm.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for project managers',
  ),
  'poker' => array(
    'Poker',
    'http://poker.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for serious players and enthusiasts of poker',
  ),
  'politics' => array(
    'Politics',
    'http://politics.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for people interested in governments, policies, and political processes',
  ),
  'productivity' => array(
    'Personal Productivity',
    'http://productivity.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for people wanting to improve their personal productivity',
  ),
  'programmers' => array(
    'Programmers',
    'http://programmers.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development',
  ),
  'quant' => array(
    'Quantitative Finance',
    'http://quant.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for finance professionals and academics',
  ),
  'raspberrypi' => array(
    'Raspberry Pi',
    'http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi',
  ),
  'reverseengineering' => array(
    'Reverse Engineering',
    'http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for researchers and developers who explore the principles of a system through analysis of its structure, function, and operation',
  ),
  'robotics' => array(
    'Robotics',
    'http://robotics.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for professional robotic engineers, hobbyists, researchers and students',
  ),
  'rpg' => array(
    'Role-playing Games',
    'http://rpg.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for gamemasters and players of tabletop, paper-and-pencil role-playing games',
  ),
  'russian' => array(
    'Russian Language & Usage',
    'http://russian.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Russian language',
  ),
  'salesforce' => array(
    'Salesforce',
    'http://salesforce.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for Salesforce administrators, implementation experts, developers and anybody in-between',
  ),
  'scicomp' => array(
    'Computational Science',
    'http://scicomp.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for scientists using computers to solve scientific problems',
  ),
  'scifi' => array(
    'Science Fiction & Fantasy',
    'http://scifi.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts',
  ),
  'security' => array(
    'IT Security',
    'http://security.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for IT security professionals',
  ),
  'serverfault' => array(
    'Server Fault',
    'http://serverfault.com',
    'Q&A for professional system and network administrators',
  ),
  'sharepoint' => array(
    'SharePoint',
    'http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for SharePoint enthusiasts',
  ),
  'skeptics' => array(
    'Skeptics',
    'http://skeptics.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for scientific skepticism',
  ),
  'smugmug' => array(
    'SmugMug',
    'http://smugmug.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for SmugMug developers and end users',
  ),
  'spanish' => array(
    'Spanish Language & Usage',
    'http://spanish.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Spanish language',
  ),
  'sports' => array(
    'Sports',
    'http://sports.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for participants in team and individual sport activities',
  ),
  'sqa' => array(
    'Software Quality Assurance & Testing',
    'http://sqa.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for software quality control experts, automation engineers, and software testers',
  ),
  'stackapps' => array(
    'Stack Apps',
    'http://stackapps.com',
    'Q&A for apps, scripts, and development with the Stack Exchange API',
  ),
  'stackoverflow' => array(
    'Stack Overflow',
    'http://stackoverflow.com',
    'Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers',
  ),
  'stats' => array(
    'Cross Validated',
    'http://stats.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for statisticians, data analysts, data miners and data visualization experts',
  ),
  'superuser' => array(
    'Super User',
    'http://superuser.com',
    'Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users',
  ),
  'sustainability' => array(
    'Sustainable Living',
    'http://sustainability.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources',
  ),
  'tex' => array(
    'TeX - LaTeX',
    'http://tex.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems',
  ),
  'travel' => array(
    'Travel',
    'http://travel.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for road warriors and seasoned travelers',
  ),
  'tridion' => array(
    'Tridion',
    'http://tridion.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for Tridion developers and administrators',
  ),
  'unix' => array(
    'Unix & Linux',
    'http://unix.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.',
  ),
  'ux' => array(
    'User Experience',
    'http://ux.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for user experience researchers and experts',
  ),
  'webapps' => array(
    'Web Applications',
    'http://webapps.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for power users of web applications',
  ),
  'webmasters' => array(
    'Webmasters',
    'http://webmasters.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for pro webmasters',
  ),
  'windowsphone' => array(
    'Windows Phone',
    'http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for enthusiasts and power users of Windows Phone OS',
  ),
  'wordpress' => array(
    'WordPress Answers',
    'http://wordpress.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for WordPress developers and administrators',
  ),
  'workplace' => array(
    'The Workplace',
    'http://workplace.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting',
  ),
  'writers' => array(
    'Writers',
    'http://writers.stackexchange.com',
    'Q&A for authors, editors, reviewers, professional writers, and aspiring writers',
  ),
);
```

Comment: Why not just use the raw JSON returned from the API? Then it becomes trivial to update the list later on.

Comment: @NathanOsman, I didn't see no list returned from the API. (?)

Comment: @brasofilo: http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?pagesize=300